# primeVue Steps component: data is refreshed at each step

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I'm working on an app using VueJs 3 and the PrimeVue library. I need to create a multi-step form, so I'm using the library's Steps component. I've taken my inspiration from their docs and from [codesandbox fournit](https://codesandbox.io/s/7f24wj?file=/src/App.vue:1860-1908) . But I realize that at each step of the form, the variable that should contain the information is reset, and at the end the variable is empty.

Here's the form layout

```
<template>
  <div style="padding: 40px; color: black">
    <div
      style="display: flex; gap: 10px; align-items: center; margin-bottom: 30px"
    >
      <router-link to="/contrats">
        <span class="back-icon">
          <Icon icon="ic:sharp-arrow-back" />
        </span>
      </router-link>
      <p style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500; line-height: normal">
        Enregistrer un nouveau contrat
      </p>
    </div>
    <div
      style="
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 14px 0px rgba(18, 7, 109, 0.15);
        padding: 30px;
        width: 100%;
      "
    >
      <Steps :model="items" :readonly="false" aria-label="Form Steps" :pt="{
                    menuitem: ({ context }) => ({
                        class: isActive(context.item) && 'p-highlight p-steps-current'
                    })
                }">
        <template #item="{ label, item, index, props }">
            <router-link v-if="item.route" v-slot="routerProps" :to="item.route" custom>
                <a :href="routerProps.href" v-bind="props.action" @click="($event) => routerProps.navigate($event)" @keydown.enter="($event) => routerProps.navigate($event)">
                    <span v-bind="props.step">{{ index + 1 }}</span>
                    <span v-bind="props.label">{{ label }}</span>
                </a>
            </router-link>
            <a v-else :href="item.url" :target="item.target" v-bind="props.action">
                <span v-bind="props.step">{{ index + 1 }}</span>
                <span v-bind="props.label">{{ label }}</span>
            </a>
        </template>
      </Steps>
      <router-view
        v-slot="{ Component }"
        :formData="formObject"
        @prevPage="prevPage($event)"
        @nextPage="nextPage($event)"
        @complete="complete"
      >
        <keep-alive>
          <component :is="Component" />
        </keep-alive>
      </router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Icon } from "@iconify/vue";
import Steps from "primevue/steps";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter, useRoute  } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();
const items = ref([
        { label: "Informations", route: "/new-contrat" },
        { label: "Effectif & Primes", route: "/prime-effectif" },
        { label: "Montant d'exécution", route: "/montant" },
        { label: "Fichiers", route: "/fichier" },
        { label: "Validation", route: "/validation" },
      ]);
const formObject = ref({});

const nextPage = (event) => {
  for (let field in event.formData) {
    formObject.value[field] = event.formData[field];
    
  }
  console.log(formObject.value);
  router.push(items.value[event.pageIndex + 1].route);
};
const prevPage = (event) => {
  router.push(items.value[event.pageIndex - 1].route);
};
const complete = () => {
};
const isActive = (item) => {
    return item.route ? router.resolve(item.route).path === route.path : false;
}
</script>
```

Here's how I send the data to each Step

```
nextPage() {
      this.$emit("nextPage", {
        formData: {
          no_police: this.no_police,
          nom_client: this.nom_client.id,
          nom_comp: this.nom_comp.id,
          co_part: this.co_part.id,
          date_emission: this.$moment(this.date_emi).unix(),
          date_echeance: this.$moment(this.date_echeance).unix(),
          date_effet: this.$moment(this.date_effet).unix(),
        },
        pageIndex: 0,
      });
    },
```

and finally, here's how I retrieve the data in the last step for the recap

```
<script>
import Bouton from "@/components/button.vue";
export default {
  name: "ContratValidation",
  components: {
    Bouton,
  },
  props: {
    formData: Object,
  },
  methods: { 
    prevPage() {
      this.$emit('prev-page', {pageIndex: 4});
    },
    complete() {
      this.$emit('complete');
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.formData)
  }
};
</script>
```

If everything works, I should have a variable modified and not reset in order to display all the data on the summary page.